# Simple way to transfer cookies from current HttpContext into new created HttpClient request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, cookies, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to wrap some api request

```
[Route("foo")]
public Task Foo()
{
    using var http = new HttpClient();
    return http.PostAsync(
                  Endpoint,
                  new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
                  {
                      { ClientId, "ClientId" },
                  }),
                  CancellationToken.None)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

and getting issue with it. Cause is in cookies that uses by called endpoint.

Is there any way to transfer cookies from my current `HttpContex` into `HttpClient` Post call? I know, I can use `CookieContainer`, `HttpClientHandler` and pass all this stuff into `HttpClient`, but I would like use something more elegance.

Comment: Is `AddHeaderPropagation` [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#header-propagation-middleware) enough elegance to you?

Comment: @PeterCsala more than enough, it remains only to migrate to core 3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just grab the `Cookie` header from the incoming request and add to the outgoing one. Setting a header on an individual request will require creating an `HttpRequestMessage` explicitly and using `HttpClient.SendAsync` to send it, but that's fairly simple:

```
var outgoing = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
outgoing.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(...);
if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Cookie", out var cookies))
{
    outgoing.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cookie", cookies);
}
await http.SendAsync(outgoing);
```

Comment: thank you, but is this differ from using `CookieContainer` conceptually?

Comment: Yes, it's much different. `CookieContainer` is a high-level abstraction for simulating user "sessions" the way a browser would, and it's tightly coupled with `HttpClient/Handler`. All of which you stated in your question you would like to avoid. This is a simple way to forward the cookie header directly for a single request.